# Отключить хеширование пароля

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-identity-2

В проекте используется стандартная аутентификация Individual User Accounts.
Добавил в модель новое поле password. При регистрации сохраняется в это поле без хеширования.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, fio = model.fio, login= model.UserName, password=model.Password };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);                  
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Как изменить /Account/Login чтобы сравнивался пароль из нового поле без хеширования, а не из поля PasswordHash?

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Как изменить PasswordSignInAsync?

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы сравнивался пароль из нового поле без хеширования, а не из поля
>   PasswordHash

Скорее всего никак. Вам придётся использовать собственный механизм авторизации, если Вы хотите именно такую проверку пароля..

Но, всё-таки **лучше так не делать, потому что использование открытых паролей, это огромнейшая дыра в безопасности.**

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать с помощью небольшого костыля:

В Register внес изменение:

```
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, 
    fio = model.fio, login= model.UserName, password=model.Password };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "!QAZzaq1");
```

В Login:

```
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

        if (user is null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
        else if (user.password==model.password)
        {
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, "!QAZzaq1", model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);          

                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case SignInStatus.Success:
                            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                            return View("Lockout");
                        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                        case SignInStatus.Failure:
                        default:
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                            return View(model);
                    }
        }
```